# Atualização Tabela no PostGreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, window-builder

Estou com a seguinte dúvida em Java: como posso passar para SQL que ele deve capturar a "data e a hora" do computador e atualizar a Tabela do usuário no PostGreSQL?

Segue código:

```
public class UsuarioAtualizar {

    private Connection con = ConectarDB.getConexao();
    private dao.UsuarioD daoUsuario = new dao.UsuarioD();

    public void updateClienteByCpf(model.UsuarioM usuario){

        // Variáveis
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String sql = "update usuario set timestamp=?";

        // Inserção
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            //ps.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public dao.UsuarioD getDaoUsuario() {
        return daoUsuario;
    }

    public void setDaoUsuario(dao.UsuarioD daoUsuario) {
        this.daoUsuario = daoUsuario;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do computador do usuário? Creio que não seja possivel, o banco de dados é instalado no servidor, não tem como ele saber a hora do pc do usuario. Você deve capturar isso via javascript e mandar pro seu DAO, ai sim, salvar no sql.

Comment: O que roda no computador do cliente? Não da para mandar a data nesse objeto UsuarioM?

Comment: Pronto. Usuário está em um pc e o Servidor em outro. Queria que fosse enviado do Usuário para o Servidor o ultimo acesso dele para registrar na tabela. Não tem como?

Comment: Tem como, mas é um executável rodando no cliente? É um site? Escrito em que? Porque isso que você quer deve ser colocado no sistema cliente, não no servidor. Edita a pergunta e coloca o código do cliente que faz a chamada ao servidor passando esse objeto UsuarioM

Comment: É um aplicativo Java desktop.

Comment: Resolvi. Eu devo responder a minha própria pergunta?

Comment: Com certeza! Sua solução pode ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema que pesquisar por aqui :D.

Comment: Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do JFrame que contém o acesso criei o seguinte.

```
                // Capturar Data e Hora do Acesso
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                model.UsuarioA usuarioA = new model.UsuarioA(date);

                // Atualizar Tabela do Usuário com Ultimo Acesso
                UsuarioA uAtualizar = new UsuarioA();
                uAtualizar.updateUsuario(usuarioA);
```

Criei uma classe usuarioA no pacote Model

```
public class UsuarioA {

public Date acesso;

// Getters & Setters
public Date getAcesso() {
    return acesso;
}
public void setAcesso(Date date) {
    this.acesso = date;
}
public UsuarioA(Date acesso) {
    this.acesso = acesso;
}
```

}

Depois criei a classe UsuarioA no pacote Dao.

```
public class UsuarioA {

private Connection con = ConectarDB.getConexao();
private dao.UsuarioD daoUsuario = new dao.UsuarioD();

public void updateUsuario(model.UsuarioA usuario){

    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String sql = "update usuario set acesso=?";

    // Inserção
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDate(1, new Date(usuario.getAcesso().getTime()));
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public dao.UsuarioD getDaoUsuario() {
    return daoUsuario;
}

public void setDaoUsuario(dao.UsuarioD daoUsuario) {
    this.daoUsuario = daoUsuario;
}
```

}